# Is there an iPhone timer app that works with EarPods remote controls?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a looping timer (e.g., 30 seconds - beep - 30 seconds - beep - ...) that can be stopped/resumed by pressing a remote control button on the EarPods.

I'd like to use this app during weightlifting, where lifting time is variable and resting time should be uniform 30 seconds. After each beep, I would stop the timer using the remote control button, do weightlifting, then start the timer using the remote control button, and rest until the next beep.

I had such an app on Android, but can't seem to find a similar one on iOS.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fi.ohra.impetus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, applications are not allowed to catch presses on the headphones remote control and use it for something different than the designed feature - play/pause the playing song.